# What is the name of the constant in this formula for photon density?

Tags: cosmology, thermal-radiation

I've found a formula for photon density which states:
$$
\rho_\gamma = \frac{a_B\, T_0^4}{c^2}$$
What is the name of the $a_B$ constant?  I'm going to guess the 'b' is Boltzmann, but I need the official name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stefan%E2%80%93Boltzmann_constant) calls it the “radiation constant” or the “radiation density constant” (and omits the $B$ subscript). It is related to the Stefan-Boltzmann constant $\sigma$ by $a_B=4\sigma/c$.

There is no standards body that gives official names to physical constants, as far as I know.